# Get WindowsPrincipal from UserPrincipal

Tags: c#, .net, windows, security, userprincipal

**The goal**

I'm writing a class that abstracts various Windows user mechanics. My class knows about the user's account name and domain, if any. I am trying to hydrate a property that indicates whether the user has administrative privilege on either the domain or the local environment that it belongs to.

**The problem**

The `WindowsPrincipal` class provides that information via `IsInRole`, but it's constructor requires a `WindowsIdentity`, which I can't find a way to establish without a user principal name (UPN). The `UserPrincipal.UserPrincipalName` property is available for domain users, but null for local users. Is there another way to get a `WindowsPrincipal` from a `UserPrincipal`? Alternatively, is there another way to accomplish the goal without it?

**The source**

```
using (PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(PrincipalContextType, principalContextName))
{
    using (UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.Name, Name))
    {
        // Capture additional information from the user principal.
        Certificates = userPrincipal.Certificates;
        DisplayName = userPrincipal.DisplayName;
        UserPrincipalName = userPrincipal.UserPrincipalName;

        // This constructor blows up because UserPrincipalName is null for local users.
        using (WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(UserPrincipalName))
        {
            // Capture group membership information about the specified user.
            WindowsPrincipal windowsPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(windowsIdentity);

            // Determine if the user has administrative privilege on the domain or local machine.
            HasAdministrativePrivilege = windowsPrincipal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can find out the use for example depending on where you are calling the above code, place something like this in your code
`var userName = Convert.ToString(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name).Split('\\');` also I would change the `Identity.Type.Name` to use the following
 
`var userFind = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName[1].ToString());`

Comment: is `UserPrincipal.SamAccountName` null for local users?

Comment: @MethodMan, this only works when evaluating the WindowsIdentity for the current process. I need to gather this information for a specified user, for which I know the domain name and user name.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain No, the SamAcountName is available for local users. What do you have in mind?  :-)

Comment: @AdamStone the same thing can be done looking for a specific use I do this constantly on a daily basis..

Comment: @MethodMan in your code above you're using `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`, which is a precursor to establishing the `WindowsPrincipal` that contains the security information. How would you initialize or find a `WindowsIdentity` using a domain name and user name, rather than `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`? Thanks.

Comment: I have a method on our corporate TFS that I have written this can be done I have written a method to do so.. and if you understand how PrincipalContext works.. you can also do the same. also there is a longer way to do it using some AD coding but I have implemented that in the `What and How` I do it as well

Comment: @AdamStone you said "The UserPrincipal.UserPrincipalName property is available for domain users, but null for local users" so I assumed that you had code working that used `UserPrincipalName` but only worked for domain users, just change that code to use `SamAcountName` instead.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain It doesn't work. The `WindowsIdentity` constructor wants a UPN. If I feed it `userPrincipal.SamAccountName` for a local user it complains "The name provided is not a properly formed account name." I'm exploring other options.

Comment: Well yea, you can't just give it the name by iself and expect it to be happy, you need to concat the domain name if it is a domain user or the machine name if it is a local user.

Comment: Oh, trust me. I've been messing with this for hours. If you give [this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td3046fc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) a string like "MACHINENAME\\UserName" it will send back the same format message I mentioned above. If you feed it "UserName@MACHINENAME" it complains "There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request." I think I need to use `UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups`. First I need to put together the domain `SecurityIdentifier`. Will let you know what happens.

Comment: If I modify your code above and use: IdentityType.SamAccountName I do find a user (I'm using trying this out using LINQPad in a corporate environment). My issue is I receive the error: **Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.** from this line: `using (WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(UserPrincipalName))`

Comment: I (finally) discovered that my issue is when trying to access credentials from a user in a different domain. Everything works fine for users in the same domain.